# Scala encode multipart/form-data body

Tags: scala, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send file in multipart/form-data request.

My problem is that on server side (in my case PHP) file contents are twice bigger than expected.

How should I convert the data?

My code is

```
val boundary = randomBoundary

val CrLf = "\r\n"
val body = (
  for (fileInfo ← files)
  yield s"--$boundary${CrLf}Content-Disposition: form-data; name=AttachedFile1; filename=${fileInfo.fileName}$CrLf$CrLf" +
    s"Content-Type: application/octet-stream$CrLf$CrLf" +
    new String(fileInfo.data) // fileInfo.data has type Array[Byte]
).mkString(CrLf) + s"$CrLf--$boundary--"
```

Comment: Try dispatch library rather than crafting it manually.

Comment: @bkowalikpl can you advice such library?

Comment: @alexkvak they mean literally the library called "dispatch".

Comment: dispatch is the solution for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Strings to send binary data; Strings are UTF-8 encoded character data on the JVM.

You want an `Array[Byte]`, which is easily emitted (to a target server) by any `java.io.OutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer!

```
class DispatchTest extends FunSpec {

   import dispatch.classic./\
   import dispatch.classic.mime.Mime.MimeRequestTerms
   import dispatch.classic._

   val fi = new File("/Users/alexkvak/kr1.jpg")
   val fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(fi.toPath)

   val multiPart = new MimeRequestTerms(/\) <<*("party-file", "FileName.jpg", fileContent)

   // some post data
   multiPart << Map("fieldName" → "fieldValue")

   val r = multiPart.copy(host = new HttpHost("localhost"), path = "/upload.php")

   Http(r as_str)    
}
```